# IQueryable does not contain a definition for SingleOrDefault

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I  created a simple Login Form in C# with Entity Framework. I keep getting this error in the if statement where it calls `query.SingleOrDefault`

> Error CS1061  'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'SingleOrDefault' and no accessible extension method 'SingleOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm relatively new to this, how do I fix this error?

```cs
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace myHome
{
    public partial class frmLogin : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public frmLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void labelControl3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void linkSite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.pishdad.org");
        }

        private void btnInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUser.Text))
            {
                XtraMessageBox.Show("نام کاربری وارد نشده است", "پیام", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                txtUser.Focus();
                return;
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPass.Text))
            {
                XtraMessageBox.Show("رمز کاربری وارد نشده است", "پیام", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                txtPass.Focus();
                return;
            }


            try

            {
                IQueryable query = null;
                using (myHomeEntities db = new myHomeEntities())
                {
                    query = from u in db.TB_User
                        where u.UserName == txtUser.Text && u.PassWord == txtPass.Text
                        select u;

                }


                if (query.SingleOrDefault() != null) // This line is the issue.
                {
                    XtraMessageBox.Show("شما دسترسی پیدا کردید! ", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    XtraMessageBox.Show("ورود نا  معتبر! ", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                throw;
            }
        }

        private void BtnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First convert your query to list: **"``query.ToList().SingleOrDefault()``"** and try again.

Comment: Your problem is you have explicitly declared `query` as being the type `IQueryable`. Declare it as an `IQueryable<YourUserType>` instead.

Comment: Looks like you're storing plain text passwords in your database. Don't even think about storing passwords in plain text. Always store hashed and salted passwords. If you really want a good login mechanism and want to use Entity Framework, have a look at Identity.

Comment: @AmirHN I've included an explanation to Afshin's solution as well as an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using this:

```
try
{
   IQueryable<TB_User> query = null;
   ...


  if (query.ToList().SingleOrDefault() != null)
  {
     ...
  }

}
```

Comment: now I get this error
 Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no accessible extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) myHome J:\prC#\myHome\frmLogin.cs 56 Active

Comment: `ToList()` is an extension method for `IQueryable<T>` not `IQueryable`.

Comment: use this change : IQueryable<TB_User>

Comment: Answers should show the **minimal** code to illustrate the difference, and explain why the change to the code fixes the problem. Not just dump a whole load of code in with one line changed.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't explain the change very well, so I think that merits this post.

Amir, you tried to pass the non-generic `IQueryable` as an argument to [`SingleOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=netframework-4.8) which requires an `IEnumerable<T>`.

[Afshin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57589437/10627707) resolved your error by changing your `IQueryable` to a `IQueryable<T>`, and then converted it to an `IEnumerable<T>` via [`ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.8).

You could have also used [`Queryable.Cast<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.cast?view=netframework-4.8) to get the desired result:

```
query.Cast<T>().ToList().SingleOrDefault(); // T being your desired Type
```